Average ignoring zeros from particular cells in a row
I have tried unsuccessfully to avoid zeros when averaging from a select cells in a row.
See both images to see formulas attempted. For some reason I get the message “too many instructions for the function” error message.

please show an example

No images uploaded, how about: sum(data range)/countif(data range,"<>0")

You can use AVERAGEIF to avoid zeros.
=AVERAGEIF(A1:F1, "<>0")
For your image, I can't see in your post., I think you haven't attached them.
